# How can I find and replace value in a code block on jupyter in vs code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook

I am coding python jupyter on vs code. I am finding the way to find and replace in current selected code block

For example

```
bl[(bl.uom_pallet == 0) & (bl.UOM == 'BG')]['uom_pallet'] = bl[(bl.uom_pallet > 0) & (bl.UOM == 'BG')]['uom_pallet'].mean()
bl[(bl.uom_pallet == 0) & (bl.UOM == 'BO')]['uom_pallet'] = bl[(bl.uom_pallet > 0) & (bl.UOM == 'BO')]['uom_pallet'].mean()
bl[(bl.uom_pallet == 0) & (bl.UOM == 'BOX')]['uom_pallet'] = bl[(bl.uom_pallet > 0) & (bl.UOM == 'BOX')]['uom_pallet'].mean()
```

I would like to replace 'uom_pallet' to 'quantities' but typing  ctrl+H will search for the whole document starting the first code block.  Is there a way that I can find and replace on current selected code block? thank you for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Here is my suggestion:**

1. Use the mouse to select the area you want to replace

   [image]
2. Then use <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> to find or <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> to replace
3. Select **Find in Selection** on the Replacement panel

   [image]
4. Enter `uom_pallet` in the input box above, Enter `quantities` in the input box below

   [image]
5. select **Replace All**

   [image]

***Result after replacement:***

[image]